# Regular search works but when I try to add a Wildcard in the mix, no result

Tags: php, ms-access, search, wildcard

So I have successfully created a search box where it is linked to my MS Database and it returns a search, but I am running into some problems right now when I try to implement Wildcard into the query. I've read a bunch of people's post about Wildcards, but I am still confuse in terms of where I would put it with my current code. I've tried a few ways, but with my luck, nothing worked. Do I need to change something out in order for the Wildcard to work? I have used "*" and not "%" since people are saying that MS Access only supports "*". What I want to do is to allow the user to search for a term like 'Doll" and all the product with the word "Doll" will show up in that Field. Also is it possible, to have the result coming back with a hyper-link attached to like "ninjaturtle" where when the user click on ninjaturtle and all the information will be there? But first, I just want to know how to get the Wildcard search to work. My code is posted below. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Table: Products
Fields: Suit_Name, Product_Description

```
<form action="dirsuits.php" method="post">
<ul><input type="text" name="designername" /></ul>
<ul><input type="submit" value="Search" /></ul></form>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
<div class="content">
<h1>Ninja Suits:</h1>

<p><?php
$productname=filter_input (INPUT_POST, "productName");

$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO"); 
$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data     Source=\\server\\KP\\Database\\DesignerProducts.mdb";
$conn->Open($connString);
$selectCommand="SELECT Product_Description, Suit_Name FROM DesignerProducts WHERE     Suit_Name='".$suitname."'";
$rs=$conn->Execute($selectCommand);
if (!$rs->EOF){
$Suit_Name=$rs->Fields("Suit_Name");
echo "Results: $Suit_Name";
}
else  {
echo "We are out";
$rs->Close;}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: With ADO, the wild card is `%` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard character to use when accessing Access from PHP is `%` and you need to use LIKE (instead of =) for wildcard matches in SQL. So you need something like

```
$selectCommand="SELECT Product_Description, Product_Name FROM Products WHERE Product_Name LIKE '%".$productname."%'";
```

**Note**: I don't know PHP but concatenating your `$productname` variable (which looks like it comes directly from user input) with strings to build your SQL statement may open you up to security vulnerabilities (SQL injection).

Comment: The wild card is only * when working in MS Access, otherwise, it is %.

Comment: @martin Yeah, I actually tried that approach earlier before I posted this and it did not work. Nothing at all shows up even if I enter in the correct file name like "ninjaturtle."vAny other suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @martinWilson - Thanks Martin, it is the "%"! I do have another question, how do I get all the listing to show up because only one shows up when I enter "ninjaturtle" while I have 4 other ones that has the word "ninjaturtle" in them?

Comment: I don't know PHP but you almost certainly need to iterate over your result set

Comment: (Just looked online) - you need something like: while (!$recordSet->EOF) {  $Product_Name=$rs->Fields("Product_Name"); echo "Results: $Product_Name"; $recordSet->MoveNext(); }

Comment: @martinWilson, Yeah, I figured that I needed a While loop to go in there in order to have all the listing to show up. My other question to you is, do I combine the If/Else with the While loop, and if I do, how do I do that or do I take out the If/Else and just have the While. I am trying to get a better understanding or PHP and with the whole If/Else and While loop and combining the two since this is pretty new to me. Thank you again!